# Query SQL en la cual necesito hacer un JOIN con el operador LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo duda con una consulta `SQL` en la cual necesito hacer uso de `JOIN` y el operador `LIKE`.

La cuestión es la siguiente:

Tengo la Tabla **Equipo** con los siguientes campos:

```
id_equipo (Primary Key)(pk)
nombre
vendedor
ip_gestion
tipo
localidad
categoria
com_snmp
ultima_actualizacion
```

y tengo la Tabla **Interface** con los siguientes campos:

```
id_interface(pk)
id_EquipoOrigen(fK)                        
status   
etiqueta_prtg
grupo
if_index
bw
bw_ve
id_prtg
ospf_per
ospf_admin
description
servicio
inUtil
outUtil
rateIn
rateOut
id_EquipoDestino(fk)
ultima_actualizacion
```

Comos se puede observar, en mi tabla Interface tengo dos llaves foráneas (`fk`) que apuntan a la Tabla Equipo.

La cuestión es que quiero actualizar el campo `servicio` de la tabla `Interface` dependiendo de como inicia el nombre del equipo asociado al `id_EquipoOrigen`, es decir, si este Equipo empieza por `IP7`, quiero que se le asigne al campo `servicio` el valor de `VOZ`.

Por ejemplo, esto sería utilizando el operador `LIKE` para saber cómo empieza el nombre del equipo. Pero la cuestión es que no se como uniria esto con el `JOIN`, porque para acceder al nombre del equipo necesito hacerlo a través de la **FOREIGN KEY** **id_EquipoOrigen**

Mi consulta al momento:

> hice esta consulta para traerme el nombre de un equipo, pero tenia que pasarle el id_EquipoOrigen

```
Select nombre 
from Equipo 
INNER JOIN Interface ON Interface.id_EquipoOrigen_id=Equipo.id_equipo 
Where id_EquipoOrigen=106,
```

Respuesta: P79CAN01 en el números de filas que contengan el `id_EquipoOrigen=106`, es decir, me trae una columna con el nombre de P79CAN01 de `x` filas, donde `x` es el número total de registros de interface que tienen `id_EquipoOrigen=106`

Comment: ¿podrías por favor agregar la consulta que llevas al momento?

Comment: Select nombre from Equipo INNER JOIN Interface ON Interface.id_EquipoOrigen_id=Equipo.id_equipo Where id_EquipoOrigen=106, hice esta consulta para traerme el nombre de un equipo, pero tenia que pasarle el id_EquipoOrigen

Comment: al ejecutar esa consulta, ¿qué devuelve?

Comment: ¿Qué tal si pones el criterio así: **`Where id_EquipoOrigen=106 AND nombre LIKE 'IP7%'`**

Comment: ¿No bastaría con indicar en el `SELECT` la columna `nombre` correspondiente a la tabla `Equipo` así `SELECT Equipo.nombre`?, para que de este modo en el `WHERE` hagas `WHERE Equipo.nombre = LIKE 'IP7%'`

Comment: Amigo la respuesta del compañero marcos me sirvio perfectamente, pero gracias por tu colaboracion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> quiero actualizar el campo servicio de la tabla Interface dependiendo de como inicia el nombre del equipo asociado al id_EquipoOrigen, es decir, si este Equipo empieza por IP7, quiero que se le asigne al campo servicio el valor de VOZ.

### Solución:

Para obtener los equipo cuyo nombre empiezan con `IP7`, podemos usar [`nombre LIKE 'IP7%'`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

#### Opción 1:

```
UPDATE Interface AS I
    INNER JOIN Equipo AS E
        ON E.id_equipo = I.id_EquipoOrigen
SET I.servicio = 'VOZ'
WHERE E.nombre LIKE 'IP7%'
```

#### Opción 2:

```
UPDATE Interface AS I
    INNER JOIN Equipo AS E
        ON E.id_equipo = I.id_EquipoOrigen
        AND E.nombre LIKE 'IP7%'
SET I.servicio = 'VOZ'
```

Comment: Buenisimo me funciono a la perfeccion. Gracias